# Is there a better way to output a javascript array from ASP.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I often run into the problem of producing a javascript array on an ASP.net page from an IEnumerable and I was wondering if there was an easier or clearer way to do it than

```
<% bool firstItem = true;
   foreach(var item in items){
      if(firstItem)
      {
         firstItem = false;
      }
      else
      {%>
        ,
      <%}%>
     '<%:item%>'
  %>
```

The whole thing is made much more verbose because of IE's inability to handle a hanging comma in an array or object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a bit of help from System.Linq this becomes quite easy.

```
var array = [ <%= 
    string.Join(",", items.Select(v => "'" + v.ToString() + "'").ToArray())  
%> ];
```

Comment: Oh I really like that.

Comment: I really do hope the items never contain an apostrophe character or the `</script>` character sequence. A good solution would guard against these possibilities.

Comment: The answer below should properly handle that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/881/is-there-a-better-way-to-output-a-javascript-array-from-asp-net/960#960

Answer (score 4):

Use the JavaScriptSerializer from System.Web.Extensions

`<%: new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items) %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous class and DataContractJsonSerializer and do something like this:

```
var toSerialize = items.Select(x => new { JSProp = x.ItemProp }).ToList();

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, myPerson);
string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

I like this approach because you can create complex javascript types in a simply way.

Sorry if it does not compile but I'm not with a dev machine.

Comment: I would find this cleaner and more robust if it used `using` clauses for the stream and the serializer.

Comment: Yeah, sure! The idea was to show the anonymous type generation with LINQ